# Codeigniter url routing selecting menu item adds segments to url

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

In a fresh installation of codeigniter 2.1.3 I have a controller 'home.php' with two functions:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    public function homefunction()
    {
        $this->load->view('homefunction');
    }

}
```

I have a view 'home.php'. The anchors represent the menu:

```
<p>Home</p>
<br/>
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="home/homefunction">Home Function</a>
```

and a view 'homefunction.php'

```
<p>Function in the Home controller</p>
<br/>
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="home/homefunction">Home Function</a>
```

my routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

I have 'eliminated' index.php from the URL with .htaccess and config.php
my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

in the config.php file I have set:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Now I run `http://localhost/test` and my home page loads with the menu. The url in the browser is `localhost/test/`. Then I click the 'Home' anchor menu item the url in the browser becomes `localhost/test/home`. I click the other menu item 'Home Function' the home function page loads and the url becomes `localhost/test/home/homefunction`. In the menu of the home function view I click the 'home' item and the url becomes `localhost/test/home/home`. **I was expecting to become** `localhost/test/home`. Then I click the menu item 'Home Function' the home function view is not loading and the url becomes `localhost/test/home/home/homefunction`, the homefunction page is **not** loading I click again home and I get in the url `localhost/test/home/home/home` and this goes on each time I click home function menu item and then home menu item a home section is added in the url.

I know it is something simple that maybe has to do with routing but I' stuck and I can't find a similar problem with google. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
<a href="/home/homefunction">Home Function</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?=base_url('home');?>">Home</a>
<a href="<?=base_url('home/homefunction');?>">Home Function</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Of course I had to autoload the url helper first.

Answer (score 1):

Load url helper class. That would make you easy and dynamic.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

or load it as default, on *config/autoload.php*

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

and every time you assign you url as :

```
<a href="<?=site_url('home');?>">Home</a>
<a href="<?=site_url('home/homefunction');?>">Home Function</a>
```

You are encouraged to use this function any time you need to generate a local URL so that your pages become more portable in the event your URL changes.

[URL helper: codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)